# Good identity map implementations?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, hashmap

Does nhibernate use a generic hash and equality generator (derived from primary key definitions) for its identity map?  That's one way of doing it I guess.  I was wondering how nhibernate went about achieving this.

Why bother?  I was asked to use a database that could use nhibernate, but it is not supported by the community right now (it was in the past).  Just want to hack my way forward.  I may come back to this later and write that nhibernate layer / plugin, but that's overkill and a little bit beyond my resources at this time.

After posting the question I found these refences below [1].  It'd be nice to find a book or a web post that went through the different edge cases.

reference [1]:

- [nhibernate: what are the best practices for implementing equality?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100226/nhibernate-what-are-the-best-practices-for-implementing-equality/2100478#2100478)
- [What is the Object Identity Problem in NHibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752862/what-is-the-object-identity-problem-in-nhibernate)
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Good identity map implementations?

Take a look at

- StatefulPersistenceContext
- IdentityMap
- SequencedHashMap

in Nhibernate sources for a good identity map implementation.

> I was asked to use a database that could use nhibernate, but it is
>   not supported by the community right now (it was in the past).

If I understood you correctly you wanted to write your own ORM-like layer because NHibernate does not support the database you want. It can be a daunting task. You might want to look at extending NHibernate by providing your own Driver and Dialect.

> It'd be nice to find a book or a web post that went through the
>   different edge cases.

There is already a a very good description in [Java Persistence with Hibernate](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1932394885): **9.2 Object identity and equality**. And in online NHibernate docs: [4.3. Implementing Equals() and GetHashCode()](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#persistent-classes-equalshashcode).

Comment: +1  yeah you heard me right.  Thought about doing a dialect.  Although that's the cleaner way forward, an identity map would do the job too, and is probably going to be quicker to implement for me.  Also, it makes sense to have this worked out for a Silverlight portion to the code base (which isn't using WCF).