# Design considerations: Java database applications (JPA)

Tags: java, database, jakarta-ee, jpa

I'm about to write a JPA based web application in Java and since it's my first time seriously working with persistent classes and databases in general, I would like to learn if I have to make specific considertions f.i. while designing the overall class structures like building it as flat as possible to keep the count of persistent classes low and the database structure simple. I really don't expect long explanations but would like to get a short overview of general considerations which might not appear to be that obvious to one who is unexperienced with database applications.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Open-ended questions like this are not appropriate for SO

Comment: @hd1 - if you feel that way you should really vote to close.

Comment: It would be great to have a community wiki that recap ORM best practices. Maybe this question exists already, but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> general considerations which might not appear to be that obvious to
>   one who is unexperienced with database applications

Using an ORM is superficially easy and transparent, but there are *many* small issues to consider:

- *Object identity*. Understand the root mismatch that relational database work with rows and keys, while in the object world, each object has one identity. There [various ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100226/nhibernate-what-are-the-best-practices-for-implementing-equality) to handle identity correctly, or incorrectly.
- *Mapping Data*. First understand how you map simple data types (string, number, URL, etc.). See and understand techniques to handle convertion problems (URL or string, byte or blob).
- *Mapping Relations*. Understand how you map relations (uni- and bi-directional), how to maintain the invariants with proper encapsulation, the issue of "orphans" objects who lost their parent, and how to map several relations to the same class differently, how to load eagerly or lazily and the link with the "N+1" select issue.
- *Mapping Inheritance*. Understand the mismatch between object, class, and tables. Understand how far you can support inheritance with ORM.
- *Working with Sessions*. Understand working with sessions: when an object is attached or detached, what's the impact on lazy loading, how to deal with optimistic locking, the link between transaction and session.

There is an abundant literature on JPA and ORM in general. The list above is just what came to my mind.

Ideally, ORM should not impose constraints on your design. However, my advice would be keep it flat and simple.

Answer (score 1):

You should go through this first

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/marx-jpa-087268.html

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to make your database simpler because you're using JPA.

One of the main benefits of JPA is that it manages relationships for you.

It would be a pretty crappy API if you had to dumb down your database just to use it!

(espcially since it's typically used in a JavaEE environment)